# docker-desktop stuck at - "Docker Desktop Starting... "

Tags: docker

I've installed docker engine followed by Docker Desktop following the steps mentioned at
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
and https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/install/ubuntu/.

After the completion of installation process, I started docker desktop using command -

```
$ systemctl --user start docker-desktop
```

It stuck for hours at "Docker Desktop starting..."

[image: Docker-Desktop]

#### Issue when connection to docker socket

```
priyeshy@AMGBLR1682-LT:~$ docker run hello-world docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at
unix:///home/priyeshy/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?. See 'docker run --help'.

priyeshy@AMGBLR1682-LT:~$ sudo docker run --rm -it hello-world
[sudo] password for priyeshy:
Hello from Docker! This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly. .....
```

I've added my `$USER` in docker group and restarted using `newgrp docker`. Still `docker run` command throws same error `cannot connect to docker daemon`. I might be doing silly mistake but I'm unable to find.

Comment: have you tried starting a container? e.g. `docker run --rm -it ubuntu:22.04 sleep 600`

Comment: priyeshy@AMGBLR1682-LT:~$ docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/priyeshy/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
priyeshy@AMGBLR1682-LT:~$

Comment: priyeshy@AMGBLR1682-LT:~$ sudo docker run --rm -it hello-world
[sudo] password for priyeshy: 

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
.....

Comment: I've added my $USER in docker group and restarted using newgrp docker. Still "docker run" command throws same error "cannot connect to docker daemon". I might be doing silly mistake but I'm unable to find.

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568172/docker-sock-permission-denied

Comment: ... and edit your question with these details.

Answer (score 6):

The solution is

You need to create 2 files `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` with ranges for user and group id mapping.
An example:

```bash
$ echo <USER>:10000:65536 >> /etc/subuid
$ echo <USER>:10000:65536 >> /etc/subgid
```

I found out the solution with this GitHub issue
https://github.com/docker/desktop-linux/issues/51

The solution above worked for my Manjaro system

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me. Off course restart the service with systemctl restart docker.service and wait a while. Log can be accessed here: $HOME/.docker/desktop/log/host/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux.log

Comment: For some weird reason, those commands didn't work even with SUDO... But it worked editing the files on VSCode, and then using SUDO password. Go figure...