# Ubuntu 22.04 Docker Desktop 4.12 stuck at running

Tags: 22.04, docker

### Research

Before marked as dupe, I have done my research. I've tried the suggestion as well to add $USER to docker group, and log out, log in, even restart, execute `newgrp docker` all that is done
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415053/docker-desktop-stuck-at-docker-desktop-starting)

I just did what is written here in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/) to install Docker Desktop via the deb package, including the pre-requsite set-up repository [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository), plus the [post-install step](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) which mentioned adding user to docker group. Note I didn't install the Docker Engine, because I thought its not necessary for Docker Desktop, this is correct right?

It seems like I have entirely different problem

### Result

After installation I just simply run this `systemctl --user start docker-desktop` which opens up the DD (Docker Desktop) and it just says "docker desktop starting .. "

Here's some maybe related result throughout my research:

1. `sudo docker run hello-world`

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

2. `docker run hello-world`

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/name/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

3. `ls -la /var/run/docker.sock`

```
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0  9月 26 22:53 /var/run/docker.sock
```

4. `docker version`

```
Error response from daemon: dial unix docker.raw.sock: connect: no such file or directory
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: v1.0.29
 Version:           20.10.18
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.6
 Git commit:        b40c2f6
 Built:             Thu Sep  8 23:11:43 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           desktop-linux
 Experimental:      true
```

5. `service docker status` or `sudo systemctl restart docker`

`Unit docker.service could not be found.`

Number 5 is really weird, something I don't find in other posts. [How to fix the "Unit docker.service could not be found." error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427054/how-to-fix-the-unit-docker-service-could-not-be-found-error), here just mention about installing from snap, but not my case.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I've been stuck for ~6 hours try debugging this

Comment: I had same issue. Have you checked if CPU virtualization is enabled in BIOS settings?

Comment: kinda relieved someone had the same issue, I checked and it was enabled. All the steps here are also works. https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/#kvm-virtualization-support

Have you solved this issue?

Comment: previously I was upgrading to ubuntu 22.04 from 20.04 through command line. I felt maybe something wrong with it. So, I did a complete reinstallation of ubuntu 22.04 from a live usb, install the Docker Desktop per guide, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Also encountered this problem recently. Just copy&paste the [official instructions](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/#kvm-virtualization-support) here in case the website changes and someone needs that specific solution.

> The kvm module should load automatically if the host has
> virtualization support. To load the module manually, run:
>
> `$ modprobe kvm`
>
> Depending on the processor of the host machine, the corresponding
> module must be loaded:
>
> `$ modprobe kvm_intel  # Intel processors`
>
> `$ modprobe kvm_amd    # AMD processors`
>
> If the above commands fail, you can view the diagnostics by running:
>
> `$ kvm-ok`
>
> To check if the KVM modules are enabled, run:
>
> ```
> $ lsmod | grep kvm
> kvm_amd               167936  0
> ccp                   126976  1 kvm_amd
> kvm                  1089536  1 kvm_amd
> irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
> ```
>
> Set up KVM device user permissions
>
> To check ownership of /dev/kvm, run :
>
> `$ ls -al /dev/kvm`
>
> Add your user to the kvm group in order to access the kvm device:
>
> `$ sudo usermod -aG kvm $USER`
>
> Sign out and sign back in so that your group membership is
> re-evaluated.